# MongoDB Functions doesn't return as expected

Tags: javascript, mongodb, function, nosql, realm

I try to get result from another function and use that return values. But context.functions.execute only works when I return the values immediately. It means that if I use this way, it works perfectly:

```
exports = () => {
  var res;
  res = context.functions.execute("listTodayBookings");
  return res
```

But not this way

```
exports = () => {
  var res, compare;
  var today = new Date();
  var h = today.getHours() + 7; //GMT +7
  var m = today.getMinutes();
  var time = h + ":" + m;
  res = context.functions.execute("listTodayBookings");
  for (let k in res) {
    console.log(k, res[k])
  }
```

res will be undefined and print nothing. Any helps are appreciated.

Comment: What is `context.functions.execute` ?

Comment: That's the MongoDB function call command. It's used to call a function.

Comment: Uh, I had never seen that. Sounds interesting. Don't you have to `await` them? Aren't they asynchronous?

Comment: These functions are server-side functions I scheduled it to run. I do not use async in this function. I also try changing async back and forth with async and await but it doesn't work neither.